# Cannot infer type argument(s) error

Tags: java, eclipse, type-inference

For this piece of code:

```
interface IB<T> {
}

interface IC<T extends IB<U>, U> {
    void onMessage(T obj);
}

class MyClass {
    <T extends IB<U>, U> void setValue(IC<T, U> event) {
    }
}

class Foo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass tmp = new MyClass();
        tmp.setValue((event) -> {}); // error here
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error when using Eclipse Neon 4.6.1:

```
Cannot infer type argument(s) for <T, U> setValue(IC<T,U>)
```

but the same piece of code compiles fine using Eclipse 4.6.0 and Intellij IDEA 2016.2. When I hover over `event`, these IDEs show the type to be `IB<Object>`.

So is there anything wrong with this piece of code, or is this an Eclipse 4.6.1 bug? If it's not wrong, what should be the correctly inferred `T` and `U` types?

Comment: What is the declaration of `event`?

Comment: It's just a lambda argument

Comment: What type do you expect the compiler to infer for the invocation of `setValue`? Why?

Comment: I'm not sure myself. Intellij and Eclipse 4.6.0 think the type is `IB<Object>` when I hover over `event`, though.

Comment: what are the exact JDK versions used by the different IDEs?

Comment: The only JDK installed on the machine is jdk1.8.0_112

Comment: The given piece of code is not complete for type inference. There is no specification what <U> is for the actual event in the main method (as far as I can see). That is probably what the first commenter wanted to indicate with his question for the declaration of "event".

Comment: This piece of code compiles fine with `javac` too.